# How do you "parameterize" DB2/iSeries file in Reporting Services dataset?

Tags: reporting-services, oledb, dynamic-sql, ibm-midrange

This is a sample query for a dataset in my Microsoft Reporting Services Report (.rdl)

```
SELECT ORDNO FROM INTERFACET.DOPPRMAH
```

This is connecting to the iSeries via the OLE DB driver from IBM.

How do I "parameterize" the 'INTERFACET' part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't, easily at least...  the SELECT is embedded into the RDML file or the report definition file.

These are the 2 workarounds I can think of, create multiple datasets, name one for PROD, the other for TEST.  While passing in the environment to utilize into the report as a parameter, the report files know which dataset to use.

The second option would be to generate some custom code and dll's that configure the RDML file just like you would do with resource files for localization.

If I had my pick, I would probably just go with the multiple datasets...